# Multiple classes on content tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can you add multiple classes to Rails content tag?

I've tried

```
content_tag(:span, 'some text', class: ('foo', 'bar'))

content_tag(:span, 'some text', class: cssClass, class: 'test')
```

One class works just fine:

```
content_tag(:span, 'some text', class: 'foo')
```

Comment: I'd recommend learning the basics of Ruby syntax -- in doing so you'd then know that attempt 1, 2, and 3 are obviously not contenders, and that an array is far more likely to work: `class: [:foo, :bar]`

Comment: You are right, they were deperate attempts:). I've removed them. siddicks string was the simplest solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add multiple class:

```
content_tag(:span, monthText, class: 'foo bar')
```

Comment: I am curious, if it's not a plain string, if it's a variable like <dom_class(product)>, how can I set two of them into class, or how can I set two of them together, when one is a plain string, and another one is a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
content_tag(:span, monthText, class: ['foo', 'bar'].join(' '))
```

Comment: this works +1 but you do not need to create an array then join them. this puts extra load on your server . see @siddick solution